# With a German travel document for refugees, do I need a visa to enter Georgia/Tbilisi?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, georgia-country, refugees

I'm planning to visit Georgia next month, and I have refugee travel document issued by the German government (Blue Travel Document). Do I need visa to enter Georgia ?

Comment: What does it say on the back page?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you don't:

> Please, note that validity of your travel document/passport should extend at least for three months after the validity of requested Georgian visa.
>
> The stateless person must select the country according to the travel document.

For Germany the response at the [Ministry of Foreign Affairs of Georgia](https://www.evisa.gov.ge/GeoVisa/en/VisaApp) is:

> **You are exempt from visa!**
>
> Based on country and type of travel document you have selected, you are exempt from visa. To Find out the conditions of your visa free travel please visit [Georgian VISA Information](https://www.geoconsul.gov.ge/en/visaInformation).

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=GE&SECTION=SR&user=PEARL&subuser=PEARL), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for:
>
> - Passengers with a Travel Document (Convention of 28 July
>   1951) issued to refugees, with a resident permit or visa
>   issued by the country which issued the Travel Document for a
>   maximum stay of 90 days.

Note that the fact that the document is issued by Germany contitutes a "resident permit" for Germany in and of itself.

So no, you do **not** need a visa.